# sed - $ in Zeichenauswahl

Tags: regex, sed

I have this `sed` expression to replace "$ABOUT" with "About"

```
sed 's/$ABOUT/"About"/g
```

I want to change it, so that $ABOUT is only replaced, when it is followed by a whitespace or the end of line. So for whitespaces this works:

```
sed 's/\($ABOUT\)\([[:space:]]\)/"About"\2/g'
```

Wondefull! But what about end of line? I tried inserting a `$`:

```
sed 's/\($ABOUT\)\([[:space:]$]\)/"About"\2/g'
```

But that does not work! Also `\$` does not work.
When I insert the `$` without the [[:space:]], it works (but only for EOL, not for whitespaces of course).

I am missing something, am I not? Please tell me what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use alternation otherwise `$` is a literal `$` inside character class:

```
sed -E 's/($ABOUT)([[:space:]]|$)/About\2/g'
```

Comment: Yes within double quote it should be escaped but in single quote it can be used without escaping

Comment: No need for parens around `$ABOUT`: `sed -E 's/$ABOUT([[:space:]]|$)/About\1/g'`.

Comment: Yes definitely not needed and then we'll need to use `\1` instead. I just kept it because it was like that in question.